# How to make the <a> as long as th button in it?

Tags: html

```
<a href=# ><input type="button" value="Speichern"/></a>
```

The Problem is that the `<a/>` is the whole row and not just the button.
How can I make the `<a/>` the size of the button?

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: And you somewhere set `display: block` for `a`, just forgot to tell it us.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You **cannot** have an input inside an anchor.

Comment: according to my understanding you want this
    <a href=# ><input type="button" id="btn" value="Speichern" style="min-width:100%;"/></a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around that by using the actual button as a link.
No need for the a.